# Search and find the string in List of DTO class in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, search

I have this DTO class and in response of API i get the list of this :

```
class ProjectCode {
  String id;
  String projectCode;
  String projectTitle;

  ProjectCode({this.id, this.projectCode, this.projectTitle});

  ProjectCode.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['Id'];
    projectCode = json['ProjectCode'];
    projectTitle = json['ProjectTitle'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Id'] = this.id;
    data['ProjectCode'] = this.projectCode;
    data['ProjectTitle'] = this.projectTitle;
    return data;
  }
}
```

now how can i search in list and find the `ProjectTitle` that i need to find it and that method return the id in DTO ?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, you can use this method to find the String that you need to find. make method like this for everything do you need to search like this :

```
  String find(List<ProjectCode> projectCodeList, String projectTitle) {
    return projectCodeList
        .firstWhere(
            (projectCode) => projectCode.projectTitle.contains(projectTitle))
        .id;
  }
```

Comment: If you're going to do that frequently, make a Map that has projectTitle keys and a List of [id, projectCode] for value.  Once the Map is built, lookups are constant time instead of linear time.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Thanks for your advice,  I'm happy if you write a map for do that, I will learn from you.